# Does a notable claim in a question have to be definite?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, notability

I've asked a few questions that got arguments that that the notable claim is non-definite. Does a claim which says *maybe* or *probably* X belong on this site?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fine if the claim is like that. It makes the question harder to answer accurately, and it's more likely to be answered with a "Maybe".

Note, that is fine too. This site is for *examining the evidence* behind claims, not for reaching the final word on anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, there should be some sort of definitive claim that is being made since it is too easy for a question that makes lots of use of "maybe" or "probably" to be turned into a moving target where it is hard to refute or support a claim since exactly what it is keeps changing. The excessive use of [weasel words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word) in a claim is usually a good sign that it is not definitive, or that the claim isn't well formed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this question: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18674/were-reports-of-nelson-mandelas-death-blocked-in-south-africa,

It's not that the claim is not definite. The claim *is* definite, but the claim is weaker than the question you're asking. The claim is "it seems to a Facebook visitor that the site is blocked".

To address that claim, we'd need to examine whether or not it seemed to the Facebook visitor that the site was blocked.